# How should we deal with users who edit questions that they don't own (repeatedly!) to boost their answers up?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, edits, specific-question

Here's the specific question where I came across this:

[Can I use Objective-C blocks as properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935574/can-i-use-objective-c-blocks-as-properties)

Notice that, in the question, it currently states this:

> NB full example code for 2014... just scroll down to the "2014" answer below.
>
> It's that simple. One line of code.
>
> Beware of many **EXTREMELY OUT-OF-DATE answers to this issue**, seen online.

Now, I wouldn't necessarily have a problem with that (if it was in-fact the question asker who added that note), except that is what the accepted answer checkmark is for, is it not?

This user, [Joe Blow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294884/joe-blow) had made **multiple** edits over the past 4 months to this question, where he is not even the author of the question!

I have flagged the post currently, but what tools are in place to detect and stop this egregious behavior from happening again? A user just finding this via google would think that it is the asker of the question stating this, but it was not.

Is this not a serious abuse of editing power?

Comment: Also, note that the top answer (mine) is still correct to this day, although it is a bit of a long-winded answer. This just seems like a pretty blatant rep-grabbing attempt.

Comment: Status-completed?  That's a pretty fast turnaround

Comment: LOL, I don't even remember what's the meaning of my question.

Comment: That's bizarre that editing a question bumps it up. Presumably that's a bug - will it be fixed?

Comment: @Joe it's been like that forever - editing a post bumps it so that bad edits like this get found by new users coming across the post from the main page.

Comment: I'd say there are a few too many edits to the page in general, but no, it's not a "serious abuse of editing power". It's hard to be sure that a large number of edits are specifically for the purpose of gaining extra rep, in any case.

Comment: You say "he [the editor] is not even the author of the question", but we specifically encourage people to edit other people's posts here.

Answer (score 19):

Rule #1 of resolving edit conflicts: *talk to the editor!* You can always leave a comment addressing any editor by @name.

Then, stop being afraid to edit. If a previous edit created a problem, *then fix it!* Don't get into an edit war, but don't be so concerned about the *possibility* for one that you refrain from editing entirely! If you followed rule #1, there's the potential for talking out the edits with the other editor(s), and less opportunity for confusion.

As for this specific situation... I tend to agree that the edits were heavy-handed. Robert Harvey has already removed them, and the editor has been alerted to both the concern and this discussion.

#### As usual, see also: [In Defense of Editing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/)

Comment: Right, if you don't like an edit, **click the edit button and edit**.  And I'm sorry you have a bug in your system that bumps posts where the question is edited.  (I constantly heavily edit questions of all types.) Hopefully this little fracas has brought it to the fore!  :)  Cheers!

Comment: Should I go edit out the edits, or would that bump it?

Comment: The problem is not the editing, @Joe. The problem is that that information doesn't belong in the question at all. You don't have to bait people to look at the answers. They will already do that if they want to know.

Answer (score -3):

I'd flag the question.

You might also down-vote the answer (just try not to go into the guy's profile looking for other posts to down-vote).

Users are allowed to edit questions that they don't own, but to direct attention toward or away from particular answers is not a valid reason to edit.

Comment: Already done. As I stated in the question, `I have flagged the post currently, but what tools are in place to detect and stop this egregious behavior from happening again?`

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Manual intervention

Comment: This is why edits always bump the post to the front page, so that other people can roll back bad ones.

Comment: Nah, it's just a bug, Kate. They're never going to be able to take this thing public if you can put lame questions back on the from page by editing the punctuation

Comment: I actually just read this "answer".  You are, uh, suggesting that (absolutely excellent) answers be down voted, because, um  ... this is kind of in the category **so insane it's hardly worth discussing**.  If you propose some sort of "points penalty" (perhaps after "points court") for people who sneakily gain points then, uh .. good luck with that, nice idea.  But it's not conceivable - it doesn't parse in normal social thought - that you're saying "oh! vote down that question to punish such a nasty person!"  Can I have totally misread this?

Comment: "You might also down-vote the answer"? For what?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov There's a log of noise in the answer itself about "DON'T USE OTHER ANSWERS", that really doesn't need to be there.  Also, just about anything a user does in the context of the question is also related to the answer he posts, and so long as you're not going through someone's profile with the purpose of downvoting their posts, you can downvote however you please.

Comment: You post *looks like* you are suggesting to downvote *answer* based on edit in the *question*. My understanding is that one should judge answers on they own... But indeed anyone could vote as they (dis)pleased. :)

Answer (score -16):

I don't really know what to say on this whole time-wasting issue...

(I already fully answered it in another answer, just above, but it got ten down votes and **no longer appears** - I don't know if other people can see that still; I see it in fray.)

As Halfer says:

**"I'd say there are a few too many edits to the page in general, but no, it's not a "serious abuse of editing power". It's hard to be sure that a large number of edits are specifically for the purpose of gaining extra rep, in any case."**

Indeed, just in terms of **THE ANSWER BEING USEFUL TO HUMAN BEINGS FROM PLANET EARTH LOOKING FOR INFORMATION ON THE TOPIC,** (if anyone cares about that issue :) ) it's a tremendous pity that the "flag" I edited in to the question (see up the top here) has been removed.  the rest of this entire issue seems to be about "unfair distribution of 'karma points' or something"

(Am I right -- or is there some other issue at hand?)

Secondly: it would appear that indeed the owners of SO **do, in fact, want it to be that if you edit a question, it bumps it to the top**

A number of you have mentioned this here, so let's take that as a fact.

OK, so that's, uh, "utterly insane" and hopefully the policy will be changed one day.

{It's hardly worth discussing something so -- insane -- but apart from other problems; I for example **constantly edit** questions (and answers), often just making small edits, since in a previous drunken life I worked (Professionally!) with written stuffs.  So in fact, now that I know that - insanely - fixing spelling mistakes or "foreign English" in a question bumps it -- actually I won't do that any more, which is a great pity.  Note that in particular I do this to **popular, old questions** - and again you can see, now, that that is a bad idea since, ridiculously, it will make old questions pop up on the front page.}

{Note that further, in this case, apparently this can affect "points!" on SO, so, fair enough, if that's an issue (is there a contest prize or something I don't know about? you win a Ford Granada or something?) than sure, that's again out -- which is a huge pity.  It's (I would have thought) an important and valuable thing to edit **popular, old** questions in to a state of perfection.}

"It's hard to be sure that a large number of edits are specifically for the purpose of gaining extra rep, in any case"

I give away all my points as bounties, but let's assume that (incredibly) someone uses this technique to "get moat points".

**Why does that matter?** Many mechanisms exist on SO (including, say, "providing useful information") to gain points.

If - incredibly - beyond all belief - indeed (as appears to be the case) there is a "edits-bump-it" in place, then, WHAT WOULD YOU EXPECT than people do that every single time on every single QA, always and every time?  (Assuming there are people who "chase points" for some reason?)

Note that: now when I ask a question which is not getting any answers, I'll just constantly edit the question (changing a comma or whatever) so that it is continually bumped to the top during working hours in the relevant time zone.  So, that's an example of "abusing the insane bump-edit thing" not so much for "stealing points!" (which - again correct me if I'm wrong - seems to be the whole point of this discussion) but it's a case of "abusing the insane bump-edit thing" so as to get more visibility for a question.

I'm not really sure what the uptake of all this is, but somewhat annoyingly I got an email sent my private! email address about all this, which is all ah huge time waste.

I'm very happy to, uh, never again edit and improve questions, or indeed answers.  Or, I won't do that if it would apparently affect the points-balance in a particular case, or something.

Comment: When you edit something, make the change "worthwhile", especially old stuff.  If you edit something, then edit it again 2 days later, then a week, then a month: that means your first edit missed something.  As an aside, the formatting you use in this answer makes it painful to read.

Comment: Nah, just tinker with things as often as you want. Exactly as if it was a Word file on your own local computer. If you're sitting there idly, feel free to click the edit button to add or delete the odd comma - doodle. Your comment sounds a bit like it's 1950 ... "don't waste bandwidth" :)  (I appreciate there is a panic at hand that someone could be "manipulating the points system" because apparently editing a question bumps it.)

Comment: no, because the bump exists to both detect vandalism and to bring updated content to life.  As detecting vandalism costs cannot reasonably be avoided (bump or no), edits have to have **some** costs external to you.  The bump is an implementation detail.  So worthless edits have negative utility -- they fail to help others while imposing costs.

Comment: hmm, that's a good point about vandalism-detection, Yakk. However, It's incredibly, let's say sad, that one can't simply make trivial edits to posts. Trivial edits to posts are **nothing but good**. So, if I correct an incorrect use of an apostrophe, that's adding pro-sumption value to SO and making more money for the owners. But just as you say, if I make such a trivial-edit, there are two problems (1) it pointlessly annoys people who are "subject to" the vandalism-detection concept, and also (a lesser or indeed silly problem), points-panicers can see it as cheating. Is there a solution?

Comment: Here we go ... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267623/should-very-minor-edits-not-be-bumped-to-the-top

Answer (score -23):

it's ridiculous that editing a question bumps it.

That's a bug - hopefully you get it fixed.

Um - Richard, or whoever, if you were concerned I was "chasing points" :) Click a few thousand of my points over to you or something buddy.

Comment: It's good that editing a question bumps it, otherwise poor quality edits or vandalism might remain undetected for a long time.

Comment: If you "heavily edit" questions and answers, that's in itself fine, but it is considered good practice to look at the ages of the posts. If they are old, don't edit too many of them in a short timeframe (e.g. to fix a large number of poor posts from one user), since it will push them all to the home page.