# Should VERY MINOR edits, NOT be bumped to the top?

Tags: feature-request, edits, bump

(A) on this site, any edit bumps the question to the top

(B) it looks like the main pro-sumption rationale for doing this is, to bring to attention any vandalism

That's fair enough - otherwise how would vandalism be detected?

(C) however: consider the case of **very minor edits**.

I offer you the classic example, of correcting an incorrect use of an apostrophe.  (I direct readers to the sixth frame ... http://achewood.com/index.php?date=09122008 ... and also the rollover :) )

(I say "minor" -- what I mean is "extremely important, but, involving only one or two characters".)

Minor edits, fixing punctuation and so on, add real pro-sumption value to the site.

But point B is hard to argue with - any edits, do need to come to the top as an anti-vandalism measure.

I propose:

**edits which change only (say) up to four characters, should not bump the question**.

(Obviously, the robot would check for, say, cumulative changes so that every say 10 characters changed overall, it does get bumped -- i.e., that's the vandalism watch mechanism kicking in.)

{You could say, "I propose the anti-vandalism bump should only happen after say 10 cumulative characters."}

Note that a secondary advantage of bumping-all-edits (i.e. other than anti-vandalism) is that it brings to the fore new information.  This advantage, would not be injured at all, by the proposal.

Note too, there is the "points panickers" reason for the advancing the social behaviour "don't edit too much" - again this proposal would aid problem.

Comment: "big" -> "dick" is a four-character change. Three-character change if you measure well.

Comment: of course, biology.se would be very prone to this kind of one-character dickery^k^k^k^k^k^k^k minor but serious vandalism. Especially questions about aquatic birds would be.

Comment: Hi Jan!  Setting aside the humour :)  Sure, with the Proposal, people with devious minds can think up obscure, tricky, ways to create vandalism or other problems.  But that's true of anything (especially the current system).

Comment: Is there? You can't vandalise a post without being noticed unless you happen to stumble upon _three_ reviewers that don't look at what they approve.

Comment: Is the front page filled with really-minor-edits all day? Or is this an event that happens few times a day?

Comment: braso, as I understand it users seem to be AGAINST minor edits. i.e. socially there seems to be a feeling "do not make minor edits".  For me, that's why there is so much bad punctuation and other minor typographical woes on the site.  I guess I ASSUMED the reason "people are against minor edits" is that it wastes reviewer's time (due to the "anti-vandlism bump" concept).

Comment: "Bumping" and "reviewing" are two different things. Bumping puts them on the front page; reviewing is *reviewing* them to approve/reject them. So which are you referring to?

Comment: that's a great point.  at the moment, is every edit both reviewed, and then (if approved), bumped to the front page?  if so, then they should not be bumped (if approved)

Comment: It's different if a minor edit is done by an established user with editing privileges or not. If not, yes minor edit is a rejection reason in the review queue. In any case bumping is good so other users can review the edit and/or the reviewers.

Comment: braso - why is "minor edit" a rejection reason?

Comment: The point you probably ought to make is that a minor edit doesn't need to bump the question on the front page of **every** SO user that favorited the tag.  A handful of views ought to be enough.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, very minor edits should be bumped. There's potential for abuse, and very minor edits are the easiest to proofread. There's not a good enough reason to suppress them from review.

Comment: Hmm, not following you here.  The site culturally hates, despised, minor edits (fixing a comma, etc), so there are indeed **no or few minor edits** on the site.  For example, notice here friend Yakk is convincing me never to make minor edits (indeed, describing them as worthless) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260762/294884  The point of my proposal is to make SO a place where there are vast numbers of very-small edits - and hence, a big increase in grammar, punctuation, excellence (a big pro-sumption value)

Comment: @JoeBlow the bumps are not an issue on SO. The most serious issue is that people waste reviewers' time to gain extra points by doing sequences of partial edits instead of fixing everything.

Comment: Alternately, put it this way Bill.  Can you state, tell me, that I should go ahead and constantly and often make small (one or two character) edits to posts?  i.e. you want me to go ahead and do that?

Comment: @JoeBlow no. But the bumps aren't why you shouldn't.

Comment: @JoeBlow No, I don't want you to get away with that, which is why those edits need to be reviewed.

Comment: Hi Jan.  Your comments are kind of confusing.

Comment: Hi Bill, can you answer the question - it's super-straightforward.  Let me describe my current behaviour: all day, any question (or indeed answer) I happen to be looking at. (To be clear I mean QA that I am totally unrelated to, I am not the OP and did not answer.) Let's say I see an annoying punctuation error, or "sydney" spelled without a leading capital, etc.  So it's a one-character "typo-related" (let's say) fix.  Rather like doodling, I constantly do those all day, in the course of using SO.  I completely understand that, presently, every such edit, is reviewed... (cont)

Comment: ...so the behaviour I describe ... should I do that or not?   Many users tell me "don't do that!" (e.g. Yakk on the link).  What is your opinion, should I do that or not?

Comment: TBC, you said "I don't want you to *get away* with that"  What are you talking about?  A professional proofreader fixing typos, i.e. adding value to the site - I don't get what you're referring to?

Comment: @JoeBlow Bill doesn't want you to get away with one-character vandalism or incorrect edits.

Comment: Hi Jan. Your comments are largely confusing.  Maybe better to let Bill explain for himself eh?

Comment: (Jan, why don't you delete all your comments, which started with comedy and are all over the place - and put in an answer with your thoughts?)

Answer (score 1):

I can see an argument for not excessively iterating edits for certain pages, but doesn't seem like the best model for one dealing with their own answers in question threads. Speaking as someone who is somewhere on the spectrum of OCD and ADD. To get around it, the impulsiveness and lapses of attention, I iterate keep working at things until they reach an acceptable level and that can take awhile. It's very very difficult for me to get things right the first time. I make a lot of mistakes but I'm determined and persistent. I don't know if that is a handicap. I know there are people with good intentions, with value to offer, who struggle with these things.

That's why I think it would be optimal if there was some kind of preview option (I know there's a preview now), but something a little more persistent, where a person could edit a draft and work on it over time and iteratively until it was   to a sufficient quality and then only commit the change when ready.  It wouldn't solve all the problems but it would create more of a buffer and probably avoid a lot of otherwise unwanted pointless edit submissions.

Comment: I certainly just constantly edit while writing - exactly.  (I assume everyone does that.)  When posting a question I might edit 50 or 100 times over the course of a minute.