# Tag-removal-only edits shouldn't send closed questions to the Reopen Review queue

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits, closed-questions

Removing a tag (especially from an already-closed question) adds — literally — *nothing* new. It does not make the question more clear, more on topic, more answerable, or more specific. And it's easy to detect. So why ask to reopen it?

#### Background

Inspired by [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307009/clean-up-by-downvoting-a-ridiculous-user-experience).

The intention *behind* downvoting-to-deletion was to remove [burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) tags from circulation. The questions were being set up for [auto-deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), in part to avoid landing in the [Reopen Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/9688271) — as would occur if the tag were simply edited out of the question.

There have been previous discussions regarding [bumping due to very minor edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267623/should-very-minor-edits-not-be-bumped-to-the-top), and the rationale for doing so (or nominating for reopening) is sound: minor edits are still edits, and there's no blanket way to know that even a tiny edit didn't improve the question or add information.

Except in this case.

Comment: Every so now and again you come across a suggestion that makes you go "duh". Yes please!

Comment: Having just proposed [this suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325787/may-we-have-a-way-to-edit-a-closed-question-without-bumping-it-into-the-review-q), I would like this as well.

Answer (score 8):

It is a shame that a tag cannot be marked as obsolete, so that the first part of the tag removal process would be marking the tag as obsolete.   Then the removal of such a tag could be special cased  with review queue etc.